# aws s3 command not work from bash file properly

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to run a command in the sh file but I get an error - `command not found`.
However when I run it from cdm command it works properly.
What am I missing?

the command in `sh file`:

```
aws s3 cp s://<zip file s3> <local file>
```

Comment: it should be `aws s3 cp s3://<zip file s3> <local file>` if not typo and how you the sh file look like is it start with bin/bash?

Comment: yes it starts with #!/bin/bash -l

Comment: are in you using window? if yes remove the `#!/bin/bash` just place `aws s3 cp s3://<zip file s3> .`

Comment: still write :  Completed: command not found

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize your script try this:

```
chmod u+x ./filename.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I check on linux same issue occurs `command not found` but when reinstall aws-cli its work fine for me.

File Name:script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
aws s3 cp s3://<zip file s3> <local file>
```

On Terminal After Saving :

```
chmod u+x script.sh

./script.sh
```

> **Now Its work Fine**